# AutoFac and CustomPrincipal

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a custom class that implements IPrincipal like that:

```
public class UserPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    private readonly User _user;

    public UserPrincipal(IIdentity identity, User user)
    {
        _user = user;
        Identity = identity;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return _user.Permissions.Any(x => x.Name == role);
    }

    public IIdentity Identity { get; }
}
```

Is that the right way to register it with AutoFac?

```
builder.RegisterType<IPrincipal>().As<UserPrincipal>();
```

I get an error:

**An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The type 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' is not assignable to service 'MyNamespace.Identity.UserPrincipal'.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change your registration code. Register the concrete type (`RegisterType<T>`) and use the interface type for the mapping (`As<T>`).

```
builder.RegisterType<UserPrincipal>().As<IPrincipal>();
```